# Changes made in Google Analytics Dashboard Not Reflected in Weekly Scheduled Dashboard Reports

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have more than 20 websites for which I have setup Google Analytics and for all those I have created a Dashboard Report, lets say Report A. I have also setup weekly scheduled emails for that Dashboard Report A to be sent to me Monday of every week. Now recently I encountered an issue in the scheduled emails. I had to make certain changes in my dashboard report which I did, but the same was NOT reflected in my scheduled report that I got on Monday. To be more clear, I did my changes in the dashboard before Monday. So I still got the report with initial version and NOT my latest version, however the Reports section is reflecting all my changes even if close the session and login again.

Could you anyone please throw some light on this whether this is a google limitation or I am missing some configuration?